# Why is there a difference between compressed and uncompressed files when reading it with the ShortRead::readFastq function?

Tags: r, bioconductor

I'm trying to analyze some NGS files utilizing the Bioconductor-package `ShortRead`.

Recently I "discovered" that the ShortRead-function `readFastq()` is able to read normal .fastq files and also compressed .fastq.gz files. In my understanding, the file format should not influence the results.

```
dat <- ShortRead::readFastq(dirPath = "./", pattern = "tmp.fastq")
dat.gz <- ShortRead::readFastq(dirPath = "./", pattern = "tmp.fastq.gz")

length(dat)
length(dat.gz)
```

I get all the NGS-results as compressed *.fastq.gz files. Therefore, for this "test" I basically used the same file, first I analysed it in its compressed state and than I did the same thing but decompressed it beforehand using "gunzip".

But for some reason, I get only half of the number of sequences if I read the .fastq.gz file compared to the uncompressed file. If I analyze the data further I get basically the same number of unique sequences but with also exactly only half of the reads per unique sequence. Just to avoid confusion, with "reads" I mean how often can I find the same unique sequence within the .fastq file.

Unfortunately, I cannot share the .fastq files since they are confidential but, assuming this is not only a problem on my side, this phenomenon should be present with every available .fastq file.

Could somebody explain this to me, please?

---

[Update]
I found some time to investigate this issue further utilising an artificially small test-file, containing only 5 unique sequences. And reading the compressed file `ShortRead::readFastq(dirPath = "./", pattern = "tmp.fastq.gz")` leads to actually getting all 5 sequences just once but reading the decompressed file `ShortRead::readFastq(dirPath = "./", pattern = "tmp.fastq")` results in getting all 5 sequences twice (so in total 10 sequences). I also double-checked the .fastq and the fastq.gz file and there should only be 5 sequences in total. Can somebody maybe reproduce this issue with there own .fastq-files?

I'm using R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23) -- "Joy in Playing" and the ‘ShortRead’ package version 1.40.0.

Comment: How do you mean `half the reads` - half the sequence present for each read or say read2 missing? Have you tried compressing your `fastq` down to a `fastq.gz` or expanding the `fastq.gz` up to `fastq`?

Comment: Hello, I think you can use Biostars forum to ask bioinformatics related questions. However, I would like to know how did you read the fastq.gz files? `zcat`? Can you try `zcat *.fastq.gz|wc -l` on both compressed and uncompressed, that would be a better comparison.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers! I edited my post to explain some things better. @bob1 In my case its all single end sequencing, so there are not read2's and with "half the reads" I meant half the read count per unique sequence. And yes I used the same file one time compressed the other time decompressed

Comment: @user1017373 thanks for the advise, I will have a look at Biostars! And I tried  ```zcat *.fastq.gz | wc -l``` and it shows the same number of lines for the compressed and uncompressed file.

Comment: @Thak means the issue is with  `ShortRead::readFastq` which you can also report in bioconductors support forum

Comment: I'm so sorry that I wasted your time, but I figured it out. My problem was that I had both files, the compressed and the uncompressed one, within the same directory with basically the same file name, namely ```test.fastq``` and ```test.fastq.gz``` and since ```ShortRead::readFastq()``` does not take actual file names but only file name patterns, it read both files at the same time and combined both file contents within the same R object, therefore I ended up with twice as much reads as I was supposed to.

But thanks again everybody for getting involved!